# Spring Boot: CRLF - Securely log payload in REST API

Tags: spring-boot, rest, crlf-vulnerability

I have a Spring Boot app which exposes a REST API. I need to log the payload to be able to find errors in the JSON in the API calls.
I have ran a code analysis tools that reports the following security risk when I log the payload.
https://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm#CRLF_INJECTION_LOGS

How can I protect against code injection? I guess removing new lines only protect against fake log entries and will not protect against code injection?

REST API:

```
@PostMapping("/my/api")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleApi(@RequestBody Body body) {
```

Payload logging:

```
@Slf4j
public class CustomRequestLoggingFilter extends AbstractRequestLoggingFilter {
private static final int MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH = 64000;

public CustomRequestLoggingFilter() {
    this.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    this.setIncludePayload(true);
    this.setMaxPayloadLength(MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH);
}

@Override
public void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
    if (request.getRequestURI().equals("/my/api")) {
        log.info(message); //This is the security risk
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use OWASP Json Sanitizer library (https://owasp.org/www-project-json-sanitizer/migrated_content) to clean and sanitize Json input prior logging it. If you are not concerned about adding additional 3rd party dependency to your project.

NOTE: Last release of this library was in Jan 11, 2021

Example:

```
@Override
public void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
    if (request.getRequestURI().equals("/my/api")) {
        String sanitizedJson = JsonSanitizer.sanitize(message);
        log.info(sanitizedJson );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The linked report is suggesting a possible [solution](https://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm#CRLF_INJECTION_LOGS) of replacing newlines to remove the risk:

```
 log.info(message.replaceAll("[\r\n]",""));
```

> You can manually sanitize each parameter.

> ```
> log.info("User " + val.replaceAll("[\r\n]","") + " (" + userAgent.replaceAll("[\r\n]","") + ") was not authenticated");
> ```

Or using other [solutions](https://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm#CRLF_INJECTION_LOGS) which change your logging configuration:

> You can also configure your logger service to replace new line for all message events. Here is sample configuration for LogBack [using the replace function.](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#replace)

> ```
> <pattern>%-5level - %replace(%msg){'[\r\n]', ''}%n</pattern>
> ```

> Finally, you can use a logger implementation that replace new line by spaces. The project [OWASP Security Logging](https://github.com/augustd/owasp-security-logging) has an implementation for Logback and Log4j.

Comment: This does not answer the question if removing new lines will protect my from code injection.

Comment: @user1766169 there are a lot of injections and a lot of protections, The question is about one finding/issue in your code with solutions, you can expect an answer that will prevent all injections

Answer (score 0):

The vulnerability you are mentioning **have nothing to do with code injection**, only with the possibility of manipulating your logs.

Remediation for that, if you are producing plain text logs, is to **sanitize** that message (**best with the OWASP library that Dmitriy suggested**), but if you are managing your logs with some tool (e.g. ELK), probably you should **produce logs in JSON format** and that would automatically mitigate this issue for you.

Back to the code injection, considering you have set some max payload length, I don't think you can have any code injection in that log statement.

Comment: Copy and paste from the link in the question: "An attacker may also inject code or other commands into the log file and take advantage of a vulnerability in the log processing utility (e.g. command injection or XSS)"